# User authentication with Devise-jwt in Ruby On Rails as backend and Vuejs as frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am usign Ruby on rails as backend and vuejs as frontend. I want to design complete user authentication as we do in ruby on rails using devise gem. I am very confused after googling and trying things. Please help me.

Comment: you can read this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html first and then move to devise.

Comment: You should probably start your project with `vueonrails` gem. Also try to avoid single page app architecture to save yourself trouble. Read http://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails

Comment: Thanks it help more to learn new things ..thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I found two projects that might help you, but the only difference is that front-end is Angular, below are the links

[rails project](https://github.com/r11n/contact-management-rails)

[angular project](https://github.com/r11n/contact-management-ng)